# Excel Plot chart based on dates and name

Tags: excel, plot, charts

I have excel entries

```
  Date      Status
01/12/20    active
14/12/20    active
19/12/20    inactive
22/12/20    inavtive
30/12/20    active
17/01/21    active
18/01/21    active
19/01/21    inactive
19/01/21    inavtive
13/04/21    active
15/04/21    active
```

I need to create excel chart, with X-axis as Date(Month and Year) and Y axis contains Number of status for that month.

For example from above table I need show in Chart for 12/20, 2 bars(or lines) one for active - 3 and inactive - 2

Answer (score 0):

Add a helper col. in your source:

```
=MONTH(A1)&"/"&YEAR(A1)
```

Then insert a "pivot chart" to count the active/inactive statuses per month.

- Date to the row section,
- Status to the col section,
- Status to the values section,

Note: you could experiment with the PivotAnalyze > Group Selection feature to avoid the helper column.